# Use search function for corresponding cells and not entire range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have data in excel in horizontal way like in the attached image. I need a formula for cell G9 to L9 so that I get 1 in J9. I was thinking of something like `product(isnumber(search($C5:$C6,G5:G6))`, however, search functions searches both C5 and C6 in G5 and G6. I only want C5 to be searched in G5 and similarly for C6 and G6. I am open to other formulas or VBA solutions.

[image: 1]

Comment: What about `=COUNTIFS(G5,$C$5&"*",G6,$C$6&"*")`?

Comment: Apologies, should have mentioned it earlier, but the image is a dummy data. Actually number of rows is more than 60 so I can not use this @BigBen

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Excel 365 @BigBen

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, try `AND` and `LEFT/LEN`:

```
=--AND(LEFT(G5:G6,LEN($C$5:$C$6))=$C$5:$C$6)
```

Comment: This is working in this input example only. For example, if you change the input to 'a' instead of 'ab', it will return more 1's which is wrong.

Comment: @GovindSharma - try the revised approach (assumes that a match should be found at the beginning of each word in the "database").